# WSGI Python Template Engine used without a framework

Tags: python

Trying to build a website using Python for the backend and I'm trying to learn without using a framework. I've been reading that I need a WSGI Template Engine that can be used without a framework. Any recommendations?

Comment: google is probably more appropriate for this ... a quick search for python wsgi tutorial came up with several links ... this one looked pretty good https://www.sitepoint.com/python-web-applications-the-basics-of-wsgi/

Comment: Read the documentation for the Apache `mod_wsgi` module. Graham Dumpleton did a great job documenting it.